# How to delete single value in a loop over dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to iterate over a dict with for loop in range of 3 and delete the first 3 values not keys from that dict.

```
d = {'dec': (8, 12, 7, 5, 3)}
for items, rang in zip(sorted(d.items(), reverse=True), range(3)):
.... ?
```

Comment: keys from *which* dict?  What is the desired result in your example?

Comment: The desired result is - iterating over all dictionary keys and if the key has more than 1 value in it to start removing each value one by one.

Comment: @user3490053 that's not a result, that's a process. At the end of the day, what does this LOOK like?

Comment: Show it to us! (Please)

Comment: In `d = {'dec': (8, 12, 7, 5, 3)}`, the key `'dec'` has exactly *one* value, the tuple `(8, 12, 7, 5, 3)`. So what do you want to do to this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking, but do you mean you want to remove the first three items in the tuple `d['dec'] == (8, 12, 7, 5, 3)` (i.e. `8`, `12` and `7`)? If so:

```
>>> d = {'dec': (8, 12, 7, 5, 3)}
>>> d['dec'] = d['dec'][3:]
>>> d
{'dec': (5, 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your code pulls the whole `d` dict_items (`('dec', (8,12,7,5,3))`) and zips it up with the number zero (`0`) which is the first number from the `range` generator. It assigns that `d` dict_items to `items`, and the number zero to `rang`.

I don't think that's what you're trying to do, I think you're trying to sort the dictionaries by month, then remove the first three values from each month, is that right?

If so:

```
monthorder = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sept','oct','nov','dec']
d = {'dec': (8,12,7,5,3), ... } # I'm assuming this has more than one key

count = 0
for key, values in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: monthorder.index(x[0])):
   d[key] = values[3:]
   count += 1
   if count == 3: break
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. You and jonrsharpe saved my day :)